# Faster way to combine dictionaries that has same id

Tags: python

Lets say i have the following lists of dictionaries that have the same attribute id. I want to know which is the faster and correct way to combine them according to the id value.

```
 perperson = [
  {'id':1, 'firstName':'test','lastName':'testlast'},
  {'id':2, 'firstName':'test2','lastName':'testlast2'},
  {'id':3, 'firstName':'test3','lastName':'last3'},
]

peremail = [
  {'id':1, 'email':'test@test'},
  {'id':2, 'email':'test2@test2'},
  {'id':3, 'email':'test3@test3'},
]
```

result

```
 comdined= [
  {'id':1, 'firstName':'test','lastName':'testlast','email':'test@test'},
  {'id':2, 'firstName':'test2','lastName':'testlast2','email':'test2@test2'},
  {'id':3, 'firstName':'test3','lastName':'last3','email':'test3@test3'},
]
```

Comment: `comdined= [{**x, **y}  for x,y in zip(perperson, peremail)]`

Comment: Are the lists already sorted by id? Do the same set of ids exist in both lists?

Comment: Convert your list to a dict of dicts by ids... Sounds more appropriate

Comment: Your title says *faster way* - faster than what? You didn't show your current code (if there is such...)

Answer (score 1):

Convert one of the list to a dict and then perform a lookup

**Ex:**

```
perperson = [
  {'id':1, 'firstName':'test','lastName':'testlast'},
  {'id':2, 'firstName':'test2','lastName':'testlast2'},
  {'id':3, 'firstName':'test3','lastName':'last3'},
]

peremail = [
  {'id':1, 'email':'test@test'},
  {'id':2, 'email':'test2@test2'},
  {'id':3, 'email':'test3@test3'},
]
peremail_t = {i.pop('id'): i for i in peremail}    # Easy look-up

comdined = [{**i, **peremail_t[i['id']]} for i in perperson]
print(comdined)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'email': 'test@test', 'firstName': 'test', 'id': 1, 'lastName': 'testlast'},
 {'email': 'test2@test2',
  'firstName': 'test2',
  'id': 2,
  'lastName': 'testlast2'},
 {'email': 'test3@test3', 'firstName': 'test3', 'id': 3, 'lastName': 'last3'}]
```

---

OR update inplace

**Ex:**

```
for i in perperson:
    i.update(peremail_t[i['id']])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with large amounts of table-like data in lists of dictionaries, then consider using a Pandas dataframe instead. [Merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) dataframes by id is very simple, it will be faster if the tables are large, and it gives you more way to deal with potential issues like mismatched ids.

```
import pandas as pd
merged = pd.DataFrame(perperson).merge(pd.DataFrame(peremail), on="id")
```

You can use `merged.to_dict("records")` if you need to convert it back to dictionaries.

If you  don't want to use pandas, here is a generator that can merge an arbitrary number of lists of dictionaries which may not be sorted and may have mismatched ids (equivalent to an 'outer' merge in pandas). This is likely to be slower than converting the lists to dictionaries but as efficient as possible using lists.

```
def join_by_key(key, *lists):
    lists = [sorted(L, key=lambda d: d[key]) for L in lists]
    while lists:
        min_key = min(L[0][key] for L in lists)
        r = {}
        for L in lists:
            if L[0][key] == min_key:
                r.update(L.pop(0))
        yield r
        lists = [L for L in lists if L]
            
print(list(join_by_key("id", perperson, peremail)))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my proposal a simple loop:

```
perperson = [{'id':1, 'firstName':'test','lastName':'testlast'},
{'id':2, 'firstName':'test2','lastName':'testlast2'},
{'id':3, 'firstName':'test3','lastName':'last3'},
]

peremail = [
{'id':1, 'email':'test@test'},
{'id':2, 'email':'test2@test2'},
{'id':3, 'email':'test3@test3'},
]


for n,j in zip(perperson,peremail):
    n['email']=j['email']

print(perperson)
```

her is the output

```
[{'lastName': 'testlast', 'id': 1, 'firstName': 'test', 'email': 'test@test'},      {'lastName': 'testlast2', 'id': 2, 'firstName': 'test2', 'email': 'test2@test2'}, {'lastName': 'last3', 'id': 3, 'firstName': 'test3', 'email': 'test3@test3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all dictionaries have an 'id' key and the lists are ordered by 'id' values:

```py
def combine_dicts(dict_1, dict_2):
    if dict_1['id'] == dict_2['id']:
        for k in dict_2:
            if k in dict_1:
                continue
            else:
                dict_1.update({k:dict_2[k]})
    return dict_1


for dict1, dict2 in zip(perperson, peremail):
    combine_dicts(dict1, dict2)
```